# change '#' key in freemarker templates

Tags: drools, freemarker

In order to use **if statements** in Freemarker templates, the following syntax is used;

```
[#if ${numberCoupons} <= 1]
    [#assign couponsText = 'coupon']
[/#if]
```

Is there a way to replace the '#' character with something else, because I am trying to integrate it with drools (a java based rule engine) and the '#' character is used to mark start of comments so the formatting breaks?

Comment: Not related to your question, but that should be `[#if numberCoupons <= 1]` (no `${}`).

Answer (score 0):

As @ddekany wrote, you can write code that tranform the template without the pound sign, But notice it can clash with HTML or XML (and similar) tags, at least from an editor prespective.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything for that out of the box (it uses a JavaCC generated parser, which is static). But you can write a `TemplateLoader` that just delegates to another `TemplateLoader`, but replaces the `Reader` with a `FilterReader` that replaces `[%` and `[/%` and `[%--` and `--%]` with `[#`, etc. Then then you can use `%` instead of `#` in the FreeMarker tags. (It's somewhat confusing though, as error messages will still use `#`, etc.)